# sort value of key from object of array that key is optional type in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

What is the best practice for me to sort an object of array by value of key that key is optional type from Object?  I have following code that works if num is not optional type However, I got error that `Object is possibly 'undefined'.`

```
type Filter = {
    a: number;
    num?: number

}
const filter: Filter[] = [{a: 1, num: 10}, {a: 1, num: 12}, {a: 1, num: 5}]
filter.sort((a,b)=> (a.num > b.num ? 1 : -1))
console.log(filter)
```

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link to code)](https://tsplay.dev/ND5Exm), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: what's the expected behavior for `[ {a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3, num: 10}]`

Comment: also do you mean `const filter: Filter[]` instead of `const filter: Filter`?

Comment: ` {a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3, num: 10}]` I expected to be ` {a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3, num: 10}]`

Comment: consider explain a bit more in the question, for example "elements with undefined `num` should be placed before those have a defined value."

Answer (score 1):

2 options come to my mind:

1. The obvious one: use a type where `num` is not optional. You can use the `Required` utility type if you do not want to keep both types without rewriting the properties.
2. If you cannot change the type, that probably means you really want that property to be optional. So you simply should check for it in your sort function. You need to check if `num` is `undefined` and decide what to return when that occurs. When you check it, Typescript will infer everything that falls out of that condition will be defined.
   For instance:

```js
filter.sort((a,b)=> {
  if (typeof a.num === 'undefined' || typeof b.num === 'undefined') {
    return 0;
  }
  return (a.num > b.num ? 1 : -1)
})
```

Comment: Yeah, the crux of this question is deciding what to do when `num` is `undefined`.  I'd really recommend against the particular choice here, though, since it's not a consistent comparison function.  Among other things, comparison functions should be *transitive*, but your function will have `{a: 1}` compare as equal to both `{a: 2, num: 2}` and `{a: 3, num: 3}`, which will not compare equal to each other.  This will yield "implementation defined" sorting results, which is unlikely to be what anyone wants.  Maybe `(a.num ?? -Infinity) - (b.num ?? Infinity) ` instead? ‍♂️

Comment: @jcalz yeah. My intention was not  to create an ideal sorting algorithm for the OP problem. There is no right solution without knowing how an undefined num impacts the order exactly. Maybe `filter.a` is relevant to the order, so it should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

To add to [AqueleHugo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67896617/2501304), I wanted to keep the field optional (to correctly reflect the 3rd party's interface), but still keep it clean, simple and readable, so I've gone with this and it works well for my situation:

```
interface WebPage {
  // ...
  order?: number;
}

const sortPages = (pages: WebPage[]): WebPage[] => {
    return pages.filter(p => p.order).sort((p1, p2) => Number(p1.order) - Number(p2.order));
}
```

Hopefully someone else finds this useful!